# USB camera live Streaming over RTMP having issue in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtmp, live-video, usb-camera

I am using https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera library to preview USB camera to **texture view** and for streaming, I am using https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java  library.

I have used the RtmpCamera2 class for streaming and UVCCameraTextureView to render the output to the device. My issue is that when I start the streaming, only audio packets are sent. sendVideo() is not calling from **SrsFlvMuxer**. It will be great if anyone having some solution regarding this issue.

Here is my code I have implemented so far :

```
RtmpCamera2 rtmpCamera2 = new RtmpCamera2(mUVCCameraTextureView, MyActivity.this);
```

On button click of "start stream" I have wrote below lines:

```
if (!rtmpCamera2.isStreaming()) {
        if (rtmpCamera2.isRecording() || rtmpCamera2.prepareAudio() && rtmpCamera2.prepareVideo()) {
            rtmpCamera2.startStream(STREAM_URL);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Error preparing stream, This device cant do it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        rtmpCamera2.stopStream();
   }
```

Note: I have added rtmp-rtsp library as dependency in UVCCamera project and the usb camera preview is visible in the android device.

Comment: Can you show the code you've implemented so far ?

Comment: First of all, have you tried this camera with another app or another camera with your app? It is possible that camera does not produce decodable video stream.

Comment: @Nanev I have checked another camera with my app but nothing changed.

Comment: @MickaelB. I have updated the question and you can see the code I've implemented so far.

Comment: You can try these:https://github.com/ant-media/LibRtmp-Client-for-Android and https://github.com/ant-media/LiveVideoBroadcaster